# How to set class name of current anchor from js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written this simple js code to render two anchor elements to the html files.

```
//<a href="a1link,html">Link1</a>
let aElement1 = document.createElement("a");
aElement1.href = "a1link.html";
aElement1.innerHTML = "Link1";
document.body.appendChild(aElement1);

//<a href="a2link.html">Link2</a>
let aElement2 = document.createElement("a");
aElement2.href = "a2link.html";
aElement2.innerHTML = "Link2";
document.body.appendChild(aElement2);
```

The `a1link.html` and `a2link.html` are almost the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>A1 Link</title>

    <style>
        a {
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            background-color: #222222;
            margin: 2px;
        }

        .active {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A1 Link</h1>
    <script src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to make the current anchor a class named `active`. I have tried with if else and the result was both of them got the active class.

I also tried with `addEventListener` method with click type parameter but, the result was working until the site refreshes and directs to the other link.

I am trying this in VS code with the `file:///` protocol.

What do I need is some JS code to know on what site it is and make the current link of that site a class of active but the others have to remain without the class.

Comment: What do you mean by "current anchor"? Clicking on the link goes to the `href` URL, so the link doesn't stay active.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion. How do I say better I have two simple pages and the anchor elements are being rendered from js file. How to make site one clicked and loaded it own link with class active and the same goes for site two it own link with class active.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want. Are these links on the target pages so they need to be active after you reload?

Comment: Yes working as the default <a class="active></a>. The code you provided to me actually solves my problem thanks. I also tried it now with ```replace``` method instead of ```match```  and matched their filenames.

Comment: @d4shm1r, Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the perfect question and how to create a [Minimal , Complete and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the current location with the URL in the link, and add the `active` class if they match.

```js
//<a href="a1link,html">Link1</a>
let aElement1 = document.createElement("a");
aElement1.href = "a1link.html";
aElement1.innerHTML = "Link1";
document.body.appendChild(aElement1);
if (window.location.href.match(/a1link\.html/) {
  aElement1.classList.add('active');
}

//<a href="a2link.html">Link2</a>
let aElement2 = document.createElement("a");
aElement2.href = "a2link.html";
aElement2.innerHTML = "Link2";
document.body.appendChild(aElement2);
if (window.location.href.match(/a2link\.html/) {
  aElement2.classList.add('active');
}
```